# Google Sheet cell displaying number is different than actual content in it added by apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I check what is in the records using following lines:
records.forEach(logValue);

```js
//Used to log values in a records, array
function logValue(value) {
 Logger.log(value);
}
```

I get following logs:

11:47:01 AM Info    Mobile number: +91-6297273421

11:47:01 AM Info    Mobile number: +91-7065694068

11:47:01 AM Info    Mobile number: +91-6294185772

11:47:02 AM Info    Mobile number: +91-7751905668

11:47:02 AM Info    Mobile number: +91-7847051469

11:47:02 AM Info    Mobile number: +91-9477819453

So far so good. But following code I don't understand why my google sheet gets something different. Mobile numbers are displayed without '+91' and last three digits are different than what in the 'records' logged in the above.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Apps Script code used for adding records into google sheets is below:

```js
function saveDataToSheet(records)
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19lsg39M5dHejCvcIhv3CDRFoLdx7EVVc-sedguVlNfA/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  for(var r=0;r<records.length;r++)
  {
    sheet.appendRow([records[r].mobile]);
    Logger.log("Mobile number: "+[records[r].mobile]);
  }
  
}
```

What I have expected is displayed value and cell value should be same in google sheet. I don't get this why displayed value is different than cell actual value - which I see when I double click within the cell.

Can any once points me out what is going on? Please. Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbcPo.png

Answer (score 0):

I got it after I look into the difference between what is being displayed and what is the value when I double click. It's +91.

Actually it is doing math between two parts of the mobile number.
Now I have to find a way to keep the whole numbers as it is.

Comment: You can try to include a single quote at the start of the cell. This will tell google sheets not to consider the contents for mathematical operation.